# Can malware migrate between OSes on the same machine?

Tags: windows, linux, boot

Someone here at work just made an interesting claim; they stated that it's possible for malware, launched in e.g. Windows, to remain in RAM through a reboot and continue working in Linux on the machine when it boots.

Are they right? I'm almost certain that's impossible, but am happy to be corrected.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but I find it related. Check the recent hack of the bitfi wallet, using accessing memory after reboot. https://techcrunch.com/2018/08/30/john-mcafees-unhackable-bitfi-wallet-got-hacked-again/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They are not correct**. Anything left in memory after the machine reboots, even if not overwritten, won't be active. This is because there is no code in any used operating system which looks in unallocated space in memory and executes anything that looks like code. While it is possible for specially designed malware to be cross-platform and to infect another operating system by virtue of having access to the storage device it resides on, it will not be able to persist an infection by staying in memory after reboot. For a more comprehensive description of the boot process, see [System Initialization (x86) - OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Initialization_(x86)).

Note that this only applies to system memory. In theory, malware that [runs on the GPU](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/05/gpu-based-rootkit-and-keylogger-offer-superior-stealth-and-computing-power/) may persist across reboot. The reason for this is that a warm reboot just resets the CPU. It does not power cycle peripherals, so a discrete GPU will still be executing code and retaining memory throughout the boot process. Malware that is made to run on the GPU may then use [direct memory access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMA_attack) to re-insert the malicious code in the main operating system. However, this will be fairly hardware-specific, and will not work if the device is booted up from a cold state (i.e. power is actually cut, including to the GPU).

Comment: Thanks, @forest ... are you aware of any malware that's able to access e.g. ext4 from Windows?

Comment: @tink I'm sure such a thing exists, and it's certainly possible to create it, but it's likely to be used only in targeted attacks due to the relatively low amount of people who dual boot (or use anything other than Windows, really). You can protect from that pretty well (but not perfectly) by encrypting the ext4 partition.

Comment: And thanks for adding the possible corner-case of the GPU ... I obviously completely lack the knack for criminal exploits - I'd never have considered that.

Comment: @tink Well that's the only other memory-based vector for malware residency that I can think of. It's also possible to, for example, infect the BIOS or drive firmware, but at that point you're modifying actual machine firmware, not just shoving something in memory and waiting for a reboot.

Comment: Couple of edge cases: VMs that allow escape to the host - two flavors of OS and a reboot of a VM and the windows linux subsystem allows windows malware to hide within the distro so anti virus doesn't pick it up.

Comment: @McMatty That sort of bends the meaning of _reboot_, though.

Answer (score -1):

**They are correct**. It is certainly possible for malware to migrate between operating systems on the same host, and in many different styles. To better answer this, distinctions should be made between virtual operating systems and dual booting, but at the end of the day, a compromised operating system can can reach out and interface with the host directly, and therefore potentially compromise it.

If we are talking about specifically a dual-boot scenario: Malicious firmware could certainly compromise every OS on the host. So, do we have physical access to boot it from arbitrary firmware? Is the separate OS in question on a separate HDD? What about secure boot options, bios admin passwords, encryption etc? We need to know *a lot* more to tell you how specifically this is done, I'm trying to give a general outline though.

If we are talking about a virtual scenario: There are a ton of different flavors of attacks surrounding hypervisor sandbox escapes, it's up to you what you do from there. Another user incorrectly stated that whatever attack it is will probably not be **persistent**, and that is just absolutely wrong. We have no idea what the initial compromise was. If you escaped a hypervisor sandbox or you booted the host from arbitrary firmware... It's game over in terms of persistence and spreading to the entire HDD (depending on the previously-mentioned conditions).

More specific information is required in order to accurately answer this in detail. Do we have physical access to the host? Are the OS's virtualized? Etc. Though the TL;DR is that yes, theoretically malware can certainly spread between OS's on the same host, both in the virtual and dual-boot scenario. Totally different implementations are applied between each, but the same goal is met and is extremely common in the malware research field.

Here is a very-loosely related question that describes the security risks between utilizing virtualization or dual booting: [Is there a security benefit of using a Virtual Machine over dual booting?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140580/is-there-a-security-benefit-of-using-a-virtual-machine-over-dual-booting)

Comment: I'm aware of exploits that let one break out of virtualisation, and, while I hadn't considered infected firmware, it makes sense that would work.  While the question was more or less academic, the machine was a laptop with a single HDD, grub as the boot-loader in MBR, that holds some version of windows and  a ubuntu-based Linux distro in a second partition on ext4 (and swap on a third).  The claim was that malware on Windows might survive a reboot in RAM and keep acting under linux.

Comment: @tink That makes sense, thanks for the info! The academic approach makes it a great question in general. I think I may leave my answer as is, though if you would like me to expand on any part of it ( such as persistence strategies on windows versus Linux) I’ll gladly update. Fun topic, thanks for sparking it!